# Laravel updateOrCreate Method -- Update the same column that you're matching

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

You know in `updateOrCreate` method we pass **two parameters**. The **first parameter** is used to **check for a match** and the **second** parameter carries the data that needs to be **updated**.

But in my scenario I need to update the same data that I'm passing in the 1st parameter. But I can't update it If I pass the same in the second parameter.

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: Did you check the upsert? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts. It does not check the second argument as it is in the case of updateOrCreate. So I think it might help in your situation.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Have you checked $fillable of your Model? Possible issue can be you haven't mentioned those columns in $fillable.

Comment: @SiddharthaChoubey I used $guarded in my model.

Comment: @BismarkAsieduAsante No, I didn't check it. Let me try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the updateOrCreate method, the second parameter is optional, so you can ignore it.

You might want to check the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::updateOrCreate()` method to see how that works.

Reading your comment, you can do something like this:

```php
YourModel::updateOrCreate(
    ['your_field' => 9],
    ['your_field' => 10]
);

// Or
YourModel::where('your_field', 9)->update(['your_field' => 10]);
```

Comment: Well that's not possible in my case because, I'm going to change the value. For example, I'm checking for a value of 9 and in case of a match I'm going to upgrade it to 10. How can I achieve that?